Why are the values in my Grafana panel not sorting consistently with InfluxDB?
What Grafana version and what operating system are you using?
10.4
Using Flux Query Language
What are you trying to achieve?
Using the Stat panel (in a repeating row by variable ${vocDeviceName}, I wanted to change the order in which the data is displayed from the Grafana default order.
How are you trying to achieve it?
Using this query:
from(bucket: "data")
  |> range(start: -21d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "co2SensorData" and r.co2DeviceName == "${co2DeviceName}")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "temperature" or r._field == "humidity" or r._field == "light" or r._field == "co2" or r._field == "voc" or r._field == "vdd" or r._field == "motion")
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({
      _time: r._time,
      co2DeviceName: r.co2DeviceName,
      temperature: r.temperature,
      humidity: r.humidity,
      light: r.light,
      co2: r.co2,
      voc: r.voc,
      vdd: r.vdd,
      motion: r.motion
    })
  )
  |> yield(name: "results")

What happened?
Upon trying multiple other types of queries including this one, each time the page is refreshed and a repeating panel is rendered, the order is completely different each time.
What did you expect to happen?
I expected the data in the panels to return the mapped sorted order from the query.
Did you receive any errors in the Grafana UI or in related logs? If so, please tell us exactly what they were.
No, the query executed fine.
Screenshot to help visualize
Default Grafana Order:

Custom Order Query:


Both screenshots show only one Row. Panels are seems to be ordered alphabetically. Is your problem - order of stats inside panel?

@markalex Yes correct the stats inside the panel.

Why you are asking about current (maybe  buggy) behaviour and not how you can implement desired state?

I want to achieve the desired order, how would I do it?
